# Материал не становится прозрачным через инспектор

Tags: unity3d

Я столкнулся недавно с такой проблемой что почему-то на одной сцене не работает прозрачность материала, а на другой работает, материал рендермод fade, что в настройках сцены влияет на рендермод? не только прозрачность не работает, а ище и металик, как сделать так чтобы работала прозрачность обьекта на сцене?
проблема решена, в плеймоде все работает